# Remover class dependendo da altura do site no refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Eu possuo um site com animação que começa assim que o objeto na tela é visualizado.
Porém, se eu dou F5 no meio da página, ao subir ao topo avarés do refresh no meio da tela, a animação acontece e não deveria..

Tem como eu retirar a classe das div's, que fazem a animação acontecer, se o load ou refresh da página não for no topo?

Comment: Tem como fazer isso sim gostaria de ver o trecho do código ou um exemplo para poder ajudar de uma forma mais consistente.

Comment: Quando você faz um refresh à página o código é corrido novamente como se fosse a primeira vez. Existe o fator "chache", ou seja, alguns ficheiros não serão puxados novamente da internet, mas de resto é como se carregasse a página a primeira vez.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize jquery, nos eventos de scroll (veja: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/), para saber qual a posição do scroll, então salve nos cookies do navegador quando o scroll está no topo da página ou quando está abaixo do topo, e então antes de executar a animação no refresh, você verifica o valor do cookie para saber se deve ou não executar.